# how get the html source code of url in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

keyword in robotframework for to fetch html source code of web url

Settings

```
Library   RequestsLibrary
Library  HttpLibrary.HTTP
```

Test Cases
Example using the requests library

```
${response} =  Get  http://192.168.1.254/cgi-bin/home.ha
log  ${response.content}
```

Comment: And your question is? The example does show how to get the response text - which is presumably the html; if you change the keyword to its actual name `Get Request`, looks like you're all set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
${myHtml} =    Get Source
```

This should work for HTML webpages and their sources. http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Source

Comment: That's the correct keyword when selenium is involved, but OP is making a get request - e.g dealing with the raw http data.